# MySQL and PHP synchronicity sanity check

Tags: php, mysql, synchronous

I'm troubleshooting a bug and trying to rule out all possible explanations for why I'm witnessing the behavior that I am.  I'm executing a number of MySQL queries in PHP (via CodeIgniter's [Active Record](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html) class) and one explanation for the behavior that I'm seeing is that the queries aren't being executed synchronously, i.e. that PHP isn't waiting for the query to complete before issuing the next one.

I've always coded under the assumptions that if I `insert` something into a MySQL table via PHP, and then my next line of code executes a `select`, the results of my insertion will be available in the next statement. Are there any exceptions to this being the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you select it on the *same* server, and are using the *same* session/connection, and you haven't used `INSERT DELAYED`  it should exist indeed, but loadbalanced MySQL servers / implementations / caching may divert `SELECT`'s to other servers or data locations....